# Backslashes "\" are added after converting XDocument to string using ToString method

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, xml-parsing

After converting XDocument to string using `.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting)` method. Backslashes are added next to the double quotes in tag attributes.

Example of my XML construction using XDocument:

```cs
XNamespace xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis";
            var xdec = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes");
            XDocument xml = new XDocument(
                    xdec,
                    new XElement(
                        xmlns + "speak",
                        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "lang", "en")));

             var xmlString = xml.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting); // backslashes "\" are added
```

Output image example:
[image]

How shall I remove these backslashes? Thanks.

Comment: You don't. There's nothing to remove. The backslashes are part of the string *expression*, how C# and the debugger represent the string, but they're not part of the value.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as ***not reproducible*** because there aren't actually any backslashes in the value and so there's nothing to be done.

Comment: Open the results in notepad.  There will not be any backslashes.  It is just the way VS is displaying the double quote to show the double quote really exists instead of being the beginning and end of a string in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslashes are here to tell that double quotes are part of the string and do not indicate end of it.
If you would have for example:

```
var myFavouriteQuoteStatement = "My favourite quote is "I like bread"";
```

Visual studio would mark this line with error because compiler would consider `"My favourite quote is "` as your string in `myFavouriteQuoteStatement` variable and the rest of it `I like bread""` would be consider as garbage that cannot be compiled.

Valid string would be:

```
var myFavouriteQuoteStatement = "My favourite quote is \"I like bread\"";
```

You can event tell the difference by how Stackoverflow highlights it in my comment.